# Twilio: Iterate over HTTP results

Tags: http, twilio

> I am attempting to create a Twilio phone tree to allow the caller to
>   press 1 to Select, 2 to Skip and 3 to Quit so that the results from
>   the HTTP request may be iterated. I am implementing in Twilio Studio
>   but if someone can explain the flow with or without studio that would
>   be awesome!

**Update:**
Studio allows me to install `got()` so I am able to obtain results via HTTP request as JSON however, I have no way in to "cache" results so that I may iterate in my flow using Gather widget. The segment of the flow of interest is `gather_address_schedule -> function_address_schedule -> gather_selected_schedule -> split_schedule -> function_address_schedule`

[image: Screenshot of Flow]

> One of my attempts was to create an HTTP request widget and forward
>   response to Function widget however after I Gather digits and then
>   attempt to Split back to the Function widget I cannot because it's
>   incoming parameters are already configured from the HTTP request
>   widget. Having incoming parameters from two distinct widget types
>   doesn't not seem possible in Studio.

**Update:**
Function widgets allow for parameters from other widgets in the flow to be passed regardless of what widget is currently transitioning.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, what do you mean when you say you want to iterate over the HTTP results? Are you making an http request based on the `Digits` in response to the gather? Can you share how your flow is set up so far?

Comment: The HTTP results are returned as JSON. The Function widget uses `got()` to obtain them. Although, I am able to pass parameters from different widgets that originate from other parts of the flow, I still do not have a means to "cache" the results in between flow steps. From what I have discovered so far, others are recommending I store flow state externally or use TaskRouter and TwiML bins to workaround.

Comment: Yes, the HTTP request passes `Digits` as well as the Channel (aka phone number)

Comment: You can get access to the JSON response of an HTTP widget later in the flow using `{{ widgets.http_widget_name.parsed.property }}`. Does that help at all. If that doesn't help, I'm still not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I need to maintain state in Studio. It appears the Sync feature is what I may need. See https://www.twilio.com/sync

Comment: Ok, sure! Sync works well in Functions.